# Overrided method not called

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have 3 classes in my activity, the first is a BLEmanager which handle the bluetooth connection and return some values through a interface.

The second one is an activity which i call splash, it is the LAUNCHER activity.
Splash extends AppCompactActivities and implements the the BLEmanager interface, so that i can call the third activity when the connection has been established.
All the interface method are inside this class now, but i want them to trigger something in the third class too.

The third class is an activity which is called Main and contain the core of the app and all the functionalities. This class extends the Splash one. Thanks to this fact i thought that i could have override the interface method which are already inside Splash.

I don't know why but when i call an interface method from the BLEmanager only the method inside the Splash class are triggered and not the Main method.

The code is quite confusing so i didn't post it, ask me if you need.

thank you a lot.

**EDIT:**

Here's the code, comments and variable name are in italian

**BLEmanager**

```
public class MDPtechBLE {
private int MY_PERMISSION_LOCATION=1;
private Context context;
private Activity activity; //contesto e activity della applicazione
private CallBacksBLE CB_BLE; //Interfaccia di Callback
private BluetoothGatt GATT;

//Variabili Strettamente legate al Bluetooth
private static BluetoothAdapter myBlueAdapt; //Adapter del BLE, rappresenta il modulo HW del BLE
private Intent enableBtIntent;
private ScanCallback myScanCallBack; //NUOVA CALLBACK
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback myLeScanCallBack; //VECCHIA CALLBACK
public BluetoothDevice DISPOSITIVOCONNESSO;

//variabi utili
private int TempoScansione=1000;
private boolean MitragliatriceState=false;

//Liste
private List<ScanResult> ListaDeiRisultatiTrovatiDallaScansione;  //Nuova Lista di device trovati dalla scansione
private List<BluetoothGattService> ListaServizi;
private List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> ListaTutteLeCaratteristiche;
private List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> ListaCaratteristicheSCRITTURA;
private List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> ListaCaratteristicheLETTURA;
List<PacchettoScrittura> Coda;

//Devo tenere in memoria tutte le Caratteristiche che mi serviranno, PARLARNE CON GIACOMO A PROPOSITO, devono essere pubbliche per essere raggiunte anche dai frammenti


public MDPtechBLE(Context context)
{
    ListaServizi = new ArrayList<>();
    this.context=context;
    activity = (Activity)context;
    this.CB_BLE = (CallBacksBLE)context;
    initVariabiliScansione();
    Log.i("BLE","inizializzato");
    Start();
}
```

Inside this class there are all the method's which handle my BLE connection.

**Callback interface **

```
public interface CallBacksBLE {

 //BLUETOOTH
 void BluetoothStato(Boolean stato);

 void BleError(int ErrorCode);

 //GATT
 void StatoConnessioneCambiato(int stato);

 void ViaLibera(List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> ListaCaratteristicheSCRITTURA, List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> ListaCaratteristicheLETTURA);

 void RisultatoLettura(byte[] data, BluetoothGattCharacteristic CharLetta);

 void Notifica(byte[] data, BluetoothGattCharacteristic CharNotificata);
```

}

When, for example, the connection state change i call CB_BLE.StatoConnessioneCambiato('current connection state');

**SPLASH**

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity implements CallBacksBLE{

private Intent mainIntent;
public static MDPtechBLE MyBLE;

//Variabili Resume Pause
public static boolean CambioActivityEffettuato;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen_xlink);
    startLockTask();
    if(MyBLE==null){
        Log.i("Splash","Creazione");
        MyBLE = new MDPtechBLE(this);
    }
    mainIntent = new Intent(Splash.this,MasterActivity.class);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.e("DEBUG", "onResume of Splash");
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.e("DEBUG", "OnPause of Splash");
}

Boolean InRicerca=false;

@Override
public void BluetoothStato(Boolean Stato) {
    if(Stato && !InRicerca) {
        InRicerca=true;
        MyBLE.Cerca_e_Connetti();
    }
}

@Override
public void BleError(int ErrorCode) {

}

@Override
public void StatoConnessioneCambiato(int stato) {
int i=0;
i++;     //BREAKPOINT
}

@Override
public void ViaLibera(List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> ListaCaratteristicheSCRITTURA, List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> ListaCaratteristicheLETTURA) {
    CambioActivityEffettuato=true;
    Splash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
    Splash.this.finish();
    MyBLE.SetMitragliatriceState(true);
}

@Override
public void RisultatoLettura(byte[] data, BluetoothGattCharacteristic CharLetta) {

}

@Override
public void Notifica(byte[] data, BluetoothGattCharacteristic CharNotificata) {

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // nothing to do here
    // … really
}
```

}

Here in splash, the callbacks are triggered once the interface method are called from the BLEmanager

**MainMaster**

Here in the main class i handle all the fragments and all the rest of the application, to do everything in the right way i need to know the BLE state, to know the BLE state i need to implement in this class the same callbacks which are in the SPLASH. So i thought about Extending SPLASH.

```
@Override
public void StatoConnessioneCambiato(int stato) {
int k=0;
    k++; //BREAKPOINT
}
```

This is the callback which tell me the BLE connection state.
If i call it from the BLEmanager only the StatoConnessioneCambiato(bool) inside Splash is triggered and not the one inside MasterActivity.

Comment: *ask me if you need.* we need it

Comment: Here's your code sir ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `Main` is not receiving callbacks is that it has never been setup. `Override' annotation has nothing to do with it.

You are calling this line to receive callbacks from BLE for `SPLASH`:

> MyBLE = new MDPtechBLE(this);

You need to move this call to `Main` class and pass it's instance as the argument.

Comment: Thank you, it was so simple.